# What is the difference between Returning View as a Partial View and Json Result

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-ajax

What is the difference between Returning View as a Partial View and Json Result(in terms of performance and other aspect)???

Can we return whole View(not Partial View) in when calling controller method through ajax??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PartilaView**

1. Partialview is a normal view that we can use it in more than one views.
2. Partialview have some design to display in your view.

**Jason Result**

1. Jason Result is a list of data or a single data that we can use in a view.
2. Jason Result only returns a data and it not returns a view like partial view.

My Model Like

```
public class ModelName_1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

**Partial View Example**

**1. Main View code :**

The name **partialView_1** I mentioned below should match with your partial name.
 The **ModelName_1** mentioned below is must match with model name in you mentioned in your partial view.

```
<div id="myPartial" >
    @Html.Partial("partialView_1", new ModelName_1())
</div>
```

**2. Partial View code :**

```
@model ModelName_1

@if (Model != null)
{
    var count = 1;
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>No</td>             
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>          
                <tr>
                    <td>Year @item.Year end </td>
                </tr>                
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MybuttonId_2').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Mymethod")',
            type: 'GET',       
            success: function (result) {
                $('#myPartial').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Controller Action method Should be like Below**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Mymethod()
{
    ModelName_1 model= new ModelName_1();
    List<TableDetails> monthlyDetails = getYearlyDetails(fulldetails);
    return PartialView("_tableView", model);
}
```

===========================================================================

For JASON RESULT we have to done like below

**Controller method Like Below:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyJasonMethod()
{
    ModelName_1 model = new ModelName_1();
    return this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**JavaScript Like below:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#MybuttonId').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("MyJasonMethod")',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (result) {
             $('#mortagepayLable').text(result.Name);
             // some thing you do with the jason result
            }
        )};
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> > in terms of performance

You can not compare two things when they have been designed for totally different purposes.

`JSONResult` is used for returning the `json` from the Controller action.

`PartialView` is used for returning the partial html content.

How can you compare the performance when both results in different output?

> > Can we return whole View(not Partial View) in when calling controller method through ajax??

Yes you can. You would be getting result as whole html. But you should not do it if you need to just refresh the portion of your web page. Instead use partial view in such a cases so that it would not include Layout or any master pages with that.

Comment: payload will be much smaller when returning json result as compared to partial view.

Comment: @MariaPithia But how you will use Jsonresult when you want a part of the page to be refreshed and how you will use partial view when you want fresh data from the server?Is it possible?

Comment: In case of json result lots of coding will be required on client side but yes it is possible where in case of partial view this wont be the case i think